# Решение задач с модификацией кода, ЕГЭ

Tags: python

Определите, при каком наибольшем введенном значении переменной x программа выведет
число 915
Изначально дано без цикла for, переменную х надо вводить самому, но я написал цикл for, который перебирает числа. Проблема в том, что цикл while слишком долгий. Может тут есть какая-то закономерность, чтобы не перебирать все числа?

```
for i in range(-10000, 10000):
    x = i
    n = 278
    while (x+n)//1000 < 178453:
        x -= 3
        n += 5

    if n // 1000 == 915:
        print(i)
```

Comment: Что именно вам не понятно? Решать всю задачу за вас никто не будет

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.